# Error when I do the operation p/p+1 + p+1/p considering p a prime in python

Tags: python, list, compiler-errors

So, I wanted to create a simple program that returns a calculation about consecutive primes. First, I create a list that has all of these primes, and then I tried to calculate the result, but this gives me an index out of range. Anyone can help me?
My program:

```
primes = []
lista = []
somas = []

def isPrimeNumber(number): #Calculate if is or not prime, here is everything ok
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            lista.append(i)
    if len(lista) == 2 or len(lista) == 1:
        lista.clear()
        return True    
    else:
        lista.clear()
        return False

for c in range(1,100):
    if isPrimeNumber(c):
        primes.append(c)
for t in range(1,len(primes)): #Here is the problem!
    somas[t] = primes[t]/primes[t-1] + primes[t-1]/primes[t]


print(primes)
print(somas)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Leleco\Desktop\primos_teom.py", line 19, in <module>
    somas[t] = primes[t]/primes[t-1] + primes[t-1]/primes[t]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: What is `primos`? You getting the length of it, then indexing `primes`. Or is that a translation error?

Comment: And `somas` is empty. Are you just wanting to add to it?

Comment: You can't create new elements in a list by assigning to an index. You need to use `somas.append()`

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- Your isPrime gives True for 1, while is should return False. Leave out the `or len(lista) == 1`. See for example this [Numberphile video](https://youtu.be/IQofiPqhJ_s) about 1 not being prime.
- Better make `lista` a local variable to `isPrime()`. That way it doesn't need to be emptied at the end. Local variables only exist inside the function so you don't need to worry about them outside it.
- Instead of writing `if blabla return True` `else return False`, just use `return blabla`
- You need `append` to add stuff to `somas`.  Just assigning something to `somas[t]` before `somas` is long enough to contain a position for `t` is not allowed in Python.

```py
def isPrimeNumber(number): #Calculate whether number is prime or not
    lista = []
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            lista.append(i)
    return len(lista) == 2

primes = []
for c in range(1,100):
    if isPrimeNumber(c):
        primes.append(c)

somas = []
for t in range(1,len(primes)):
    somas.apppend(primes[t]/primes[t-1] + primes[t-1]/primes[t])

print(primes)
print(somas)
```

PS: Using `zip`, the calculation of the sums could also be written as:

```
for p0, p1 in zip(primes[:-1],primes[1:]):
    somas.append(p1/p0 + p0/p1)
```

Comment: thk you so much! About 1, I have already corrected about that, it whas only a test! Thank you so much! <3